# Manipulating data with a function

Tags: php, html, forms, function

First off I am trying to get three inputs from a  user in a text box and call some PHP function to manipulate that data. I am not sure how things work exactly with PHP & HTML.

Below is a short example of what exactly I am trying to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> Distance </title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

        function distance($lat, $lng, $d){
            $distance = ($lat - $lng) / $d;
            return $distance;
        }


        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            distance($_POST['lat','lng','d']);
        }

    ?>

    Lattitude  <input type="text" name="lat"</> 
    <br> Longitude <input type="text" name="lng" />
    <br> Distance <input type="text" name="d" />

    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

    </body>
</html>
```

My error is at:

```
distance($_POST['lat','lng','d']);
```

Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: As you want to do it it's not possible, but this: `distance($_POST['lat'],$_POST['lng'],$_POST['d'])`  also you probably want to print the return value of the function

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i echo out the value of the function but nothing is ouputted after i click submit

Comment: 1) You need form tags with the method post around your input fields 2) Where is your third input?

Comment: Okay so for clarification, whenever i am trying to output some value that a user inputs i need to enclose them in form tags? and i made a simple typo it's right there, i forgot to remove the "<"  in the latitude field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> distance($_POST['lat','lng','d']); <<<< Is this possible in PHP

No you can't do this. `$_POST` is an array and you can't have a comma separated index. But what you probably want to do is this:

```
distance($_POST['lat'], $_POST['lng'], $_POST['d'])
```

So you send 3 arguments to the function and each index separated from the other by comma.

Next you also probably want to output the return value of your function, e.g.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo distance($_POST['lat','lng','d']);
}
```

And last, but most important is, that you have to enclose your input tags with a form tag, so you can send your form back to the server with the POST method, e.g.

```
<form method="post">
    Lattitude  <input type="text" name="lat" /> 

    <br> Longitude <input type="text" name="lng" />
    <br> Distance <input type="text" name="d" />

    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: @Candole You're welcome. Enjoy your day :) (FYI: Here is a little tutorial how to work with forms and PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)